# php... inserting (appending) a record into a semicolon table using a text file?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using a text file with a semicolon table inside... I have learned how to grab my data. Specifically grab whatever columns I need...

```
<?php

$statfile=$_GET['scd'];

if ($statfile=='')
{
    $statfile="/et3mach/status.txt";
}

$temps = array();
$brdhover = array();
if (($handle = fopen($statfile, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
    {
        if(substr(trim($data[0]), 0, 3) == 'BRD')
        {
            $board = trim($data[0]);          // get the index (e.g "BRD 0") & strip leading or trailing blanks
            $temp =  trim($data[10]);         // the tempreture data is the 10th field; trim that also, to be safe.
            $temps[ $board ] = $temp;
            $brdhover[ $board ] = $data[11];  // Field 11 is the "hover" text; don't trim that for now...
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

But inserting is more difficult and all I can come up with is inserting a record into one text file...

```
<?php
$companyfile = "data/company.txt";
if (isset($_POST['company']))
{
    $newData = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['company']));
    $handle = fopen($companyfile, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $newData);
    fclose($handle);
}
// ----------------------------
if (file_exists($companyfile)) {
    $companyData = file_get_contents($companyfile);
}
```

How do I combine these two functions so I can insert and append messages using the html form? In this case I have a semicolon table with one column. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fclose()` Use can use the wrapper function [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) with `FILE_APPEND` flag as show here

```
file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: I will try this... and read up more on this function... You certainly answered my question, Thank you!!! :)

Comment: @Malanno When someone answers your question, you should mark the question as *accepted* or at least upvote it.

Comment: yes I should, I'm sorry I was rewriting the code and was getting around to it.. :)